# How do i multiply decimal point in shell

Tags: shell

```
price=22.22
qty=33
let "total_sales=$price*$qty"
```

It gives me an error

> invalid arithmetic operator

Is there anyway i can multiply both value?

Comment: In which shell?

Comment: `echo "scale=2 ;$price*$qty"|bc`

Comment: @Justpee, I have noticed from your previous questions, that you are not accepting answers provided to any of your questions, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Not doing so, provides lesser response for your subsequent questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `awk` for floating point arithmetic, as some of the shells, including `bash` does not support floating point arithmetic.

```
awk -v price=22.22 -v qty=33 'BEGIN{total_sales=(price*qty); print total_sales;}'
733.26
```

Or) if your variables are defined in shell, you can import them to `Awk` as below. Note that the variables under `shell` and `awk` are different.

```
price="22.22"
qty="33"

awk -v price="${price}" -v qty="${qty}" 'BEGIN{total_sales=(price*qty); print total_sales}'
733.26
```

Store it in a variable as

```
price="22.22"
qty="33"
unset total_sales
total_sales=$(awk -v price="${price}" -v qty="${qty}" 'BEGIN{print (price*qty)}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work because shell arithmetic does not support floating point operations.

If you want to avoid having to call an external program (which would be quite inefficient in a case there a lot of those calculations would have to be done), you can use integer arithmetic to get to the solution.

First, multiply each operand by a power of 10 just enough to get rid of the decimal part.  In this case, multiply 22.22 by 100.  This step could be generalized to automatically establish the proper factor depending on the number of digits, or you can simply use a huge factor of 10 and make sure you never have a number with more digits after the decimal point than you can handle.

```
X=2222
Y=33
FACTOR=100
```

Then multiply X by Y, which yields 73326.

```
A=$(($X * $Y))
```

Then divide 73326 by the 100 factor used above, with the `/` operator.  You get 733, the integer part of the result.

```
B=$(( $A / $FACTOR ))
```

Then use the modulo (integer division remainder) operation, `%`, to get the remainder, which will be your decimal portion.

```
C=$(( $A % $FACTOR ))
```

The final result is then simply :

```
R="$B.$C"
```

You can have it expressed as a one-liner :

```
X=2222
Y=33
FACTOR=100
RESULT=$((X*Y/FACTOR)).$((X*Y%FACTOR))
```

Comment: `IMHO`, this is a pretty roundabout way to achieve such a trivial task, even if it answers the question. But generation of `FACTOR` seems to be hard-coded, you could add to dynamically generate that to make it a bit better.

Comment: Actually, my solution is 4 lines of very, very simple code.  Compare that with the awk solution, which is a one-liner, but that line is a lot more complex.  Again, my aim was to describe a solution that you also could work with in case you have a lot of these calculations to perform, and invoking an external program would become unwieldy.

Comment: you call my `Awk` logic complex? `Awk` is _an external program_, _`Yes`_ but it is part of all major distributions these days and the one I have provided is a portable solution, not using any version specific features. And it runs fastest compared to any number of steps you do in `bash`.  So do not claim yours efficient/portable than mine, because _it ain't_ ! Good luck!

Comment: I did a quick test.  In a for loop with 1000 iterations, my solution executes in less than 0.04 second, while yours requires about 0.75 second.  Launching processes is (relatively) slow, even if the program itself is highly efficient.  That being said, I am not criticizing your solution for being either complex or non-standard, nor saying my proposed solution is the right one in every case.