# How to multiply float value with variable(command is stored in this variable)?

Tags: linux, bash

```
res=$(echo `sed '1d'| cut -d ';' -f3 |sort -nrk3 | head -1`)
a=0.15
echo `expr $a \* $res`
```

I have this piece of code and this will print **50000** when echo `"$res"`  is executed and I want to multiply this answer with a float number say **0.10**. How can I perform this operation in bash?

I've tried using the **expr** command but isn't working, giving me the error `expr: non-integer argument`. Is there any other way so that I'll get the result as `5000`.

Suppose the input provided will be in the following format:

```
Empld;EmpName:Salary
1231;Tushar;20000
5671;Dick;35000
7712;Harry;50000
8712;Reenee;25000
4444;Bakul;50000
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in form code in your question(keep it up). It will be really nice if you could add samples of input and expected output too in your question so that we can get better understanding of your question, moreover I am pretty sure this could be done in a single `awk` or `sed` etc too, so kindly do update your post and let us know, thank you.

Comment: There is no input to be processed in the above command. By the looks of things, you can everything in one awk statement though

Comment: did my solution worked for you?

Comment: I have updated the question @JatinMehrotra Your solution didn't work for me, kindly reconsider it. Thank you.

Comment: even i updated my answer, kindly copy paste the script as well make contents.txt which has salaries.
better to have my script and contents.txt in same directory to avoid writing complete path in the script `res=$(less /path/to/contents.txt| echo `sed '1d'| cut -d ';' -f3 |sort -nrk3 | head -1`)`, you can just mention contents.txt if they are in same directory.
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me

```
a=1.5
res=200
RES=$(echo "scale=4; $a*$res" | bc)
echo $RES
```

updated after question update lets say suppose contents.txt file has this content.

```
Empld;EmpName:Salary
1231;Tushar;20000
5671;Dick;35000
7712;Harry;50000
8712;Reenee;25000
4444;Bakul;50000
```

in order to get 5000 as you mentioned I created this script stack_ans.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

res=$(less /path/to/contents.txt| echo `sed '1d'| cut -d ';' -f3 |sort -nrk3 | head -1`)
#echo $res  #returns 50000
a=0.10 #to multiply with 0.10 as you mentioned
RESULT=$(echo "scale=4; $a*$res" | bc) 
echo $RESULT #returns 5000
```

command to set permission and execute the script

```
chmod 700 stack_ans.sh #to execute
./stack_ans.sh
```

script returns `5000`

**note if script and the file which has all entries are in same directory then you don't need to mention its complete path.**

note this version is without using awk, same thing can also be achieved by awk like in this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/41695682/13126651